# End comment mode via keyboard shortcut in OpenOffice.org Writer

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, openoffice, openoffice-writer

To enter comment mode in Writer one can use a shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>.

However, to end the comment I seem to be forced to utilize my mouse.

How can I avoid the mouse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

This will end your comment and jump you back into the main document area right where you left off.

Comment: I must be getting old... never considered escape. Tried enter, ctr+enter, tab, ctrl+shift+enter... then got frustrated and clicked away. Escape seems like "Cancel the comment" keystroke

Answer (score 0):

Found a new "escapeless" way to exit -- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Up</kbd> or down. Not sure about why this works, but I find it easier than hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd>, which is quite out of the normal reach